# Any historical proof for places mentioned and incidents narrated in The Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata, history

Are there any proofs in our present time that attest to the incidents narrated in The Mahabharata?

To add to that any proof to say Lord Krishna existed and how strong he was?

Comment: More suited to History SE.

Answer (score 3):

- Dwaraka was found by archeoligists in gujarat and they estimate it to be **3600** years old (approximately) you can see in this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dv%C4%81rak%C4%81) and  another [link](http://www.atlantisevidence.com/evidence2.html)
- Hastinapur palace with lord shiva temple old as **7000** years old
- In Harappa Rajasthan they found ruins which had radioactivty and are estimated to **8000 to 12000** years old and it was destroyed a half-million people in this [link](http://beforeitsnews.com/alternative/2010/10/ancient-city-in-india-irradiated-by-atomic-blast-debunked-201540.html) and this [link](http://philipcoppens.com/bestevidence.html)